# Extending ToggleButton setChecked not working android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been trying to extend ToggleButton and tried to override the setChecked function.

But nothing happens when I do this

```
@Override
public void setChecked(boolean s) {
    super.setChecked(s);
}
```

The state never changes.

Comment: What do you mean `The state never changes`? Does the View not update, or do you not get an event in the listener?

Comment: The view doesn't update and the isChecked always returns the same value. I get an event in the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `super.setChecked(s);` in your override so it will still execute the existing code from the super class (ToggleButton).